# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace', error with owotext library

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I am developing a Discord bot, and I am trying to make a command that 'owoifies' text,
I decided to use the 'owotext' library since it best fits what I am trying to do.

Here is my code:

```
from owotext import OwO
uwu = OwO([''], [' >w<','...',' uwu'], {'r': 'w','l':'w', 'name': 'naem', 'oo': 'ooo','thi': 'di','oo': 'ooo', 'ow': 'owo','one': 'wun','wan': 'wun'})

@bot.command(aliases = ['owoify'])
async def  owo(ctx, *words):
    a=(f'{words[0]}-{uwu.whatsthis(words)}')
    a = await ctx.send(a)
    print(f"{author} run command owo in the server {name}({guild}) at {x}")
```

Which returns this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command owo:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\discordbot.py", line 432, in owo
    a=(f'{words[0]}-{uwu.whatsthis(words)}')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\owotext\owo.py", line 87, in whatsthis
    text = self.translate(text)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\owotext\owo.py", line 102, in translate
    text = text.replace(key, value)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I have looked all over google with the error code, but all I can find is people
trying to use 'replace' directly rather than via a library.

Here is the owotext library documentation:
[OwOText Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/owotext/)

Comment: From the "documentation" it seems that "whatsthis" takes a string but you give it a tuple.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just convert the tuple to strings separated by spaces.

Comment: This updated code:
```
@bot.command(aliases = ['owoify'])
async def owo(ctx, *words):
    " ".join(words)
    a=(f'{words[0]}-{uwu.whatsthis(words)}')
    a = await ctx.send(a)
```
Returned the same error...

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it using this:
words = str(" ".join(words))

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['owoify']) 
async def owo(ctx, *words): 
    words = str(" ".join(words)) 
    a=(f'{words[0]}-{uwu.whatsthis(words)}') 
    a = await ctx.send(a)
```